# CSS3 Mega Menu and Print Control?

Tags: css

I am new to css but I have a css3 mega menu and notice that when I go to print the page it wants to print out all the material in the mega menu as well on the page. If you would like to test it yourself go to here http://gdisinc.com/barker/default.php and the print preview the page and you should notice that all the mega menu stuff shows on the page to.

My questions: Is there a way to tell the browse not to show the mega menu in the print? Or is there some other kind of workaround for this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [print.css](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-simple-print-css-for-your-site/) and maybe do something like:

```
#menu li div{
   display:none;
}
```